# How to add more than one layout in a single screen in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to add a boxlayout to a screen with a boxlayout already, but the contents of the second boxlayout keeps overlaying the contents of the first layout.
I don't think it's my indentation, is there a code I am missing, or anything.

I want the content of the second boxlayout to come last of course. I will really appreciate any help, Thanks in Advance.

here's my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                padding: '10dp', '15dp'
                spacing: '15dp'

                MDCard:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: label1.height
                    # size: 280, 200
                    MDLabel:
                        id: label1
                        markup: True
                        padding: [15, 1]
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]
                        text:
                            '''
                            [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                            [b][i]“Make every detail perfect and limit the number of details to perfect.[/b][/i]”
                            – Jack Dorsey\n
                            '''

                MDCard:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    # size: 280, 200
                    height: label2.height
                    MDLabel:
                        id: label2
                        markup: True
                        padding: [15, 5]
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]
                        text:
                            '''
                            [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                            [b][i]“Make every detail perfect and limit the number of details to perfect.[/b][/i]”
                            – Jack Dorsey\n
                            '''

                MDCard:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    # size: 280, 200
                    height: label2.height
                    MDLabel:
                        id: label2
                        markup: True
                        padding: [15, 5]
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]
                        text:
                            '''
                            [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                            [b][i]“Make every detail perfect and limit the number of details to perfect.[/b][/i]”
                            – Jack Dorsey\n
                            '''

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 9
            spacing: '10dp'
            padding: ['10dp', '10dp']

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "250dp", "180dp"
                elevation: 15
                radius: 15
                caption: 'Hello dear'
                Image:
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    size_hint_y: 1
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "250dp", "180dp"
                elevation: 15
                radius: 15
                caption: 'Hello dear'
                Image:
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    size_hint_y: 1
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "250dp", "180dp"
                elevation: 15
                radius: 15
                caption: 'Hello dear'
                Image:
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    size_hint_y: 1
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

"""


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Comment: So what you are trying to do here is that after the first `MDBoxLayout`, the second one will be placed under it, not on top of it? Just asking just in case.

Comment: The default `pos` of a widget is `(0,0)`, so both of your `MDBoxLayouts` will be positioned at `(0,0)`. You can adjust positions using `pos` or `pos_hint`.

Comment: Or alternatively you can put all of your `MDBoxLayout`s into a single `MDStackLayout` and change each box layouts' `size_hint` argument, but this is most likely not what you want I suppose

Comment: @Weebify Yes I want to the second one to be placed under it.... Please I would like you to show me a sample code of what you mean, by putting the MDLayouts into a single MDStacklayout and changing the size_hint..

Comment: @JohnAnderson I tried adjusting the pos_hint like you said, but the size of the boxlayout just changes unacceptably, how do I rectify this, and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Kivy docs:

> The class `RelativeLayout` behaves just like the regular
> `FloatLayout` except that its child widgets are positioned
> relative to the layout.

You have to put everything inside a BoxLayout to override the default RelativeLayout behaviour of MDScreen:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
<MyImageCard@MDCard>
    source: ''
    caption:''    
    ripple_behavior: True
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "250dp", "180dp"
    elevation: 15
    radius: 15       
    padding: "8dp"
    MDLabel:
        text: root.caption
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        adaptive_height: True
    MDSeparator:
        height: "1dp"
    Image:
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_y: 1
        source: root.source
        
<MyTextCard@MDCard>:
    text:""
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: child_label.height
    MDLabel:
        id: child_label
        markup: True
        padding: [15, 1]
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]
        text:root.text
    
MDScreen:
    image: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"           
    text:'[size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size][b][i]\\n"Make every detail perfect and limit the number of details to perfect."[/b][/i] \\n– Jack Dorsey'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        ScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                padding: '10dp', '15dp'
                spacing: '15dp'
                
                MyTextCard:
                    text:root.text
    
                MyTextCard:
                    text:root.text
                                
                MyTextCard:
                    text:root.text
                
                MyTextCard:
                    text:root.text
                
                MyTextCard:
                    text:root.text
                        
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: 400                    
                    ScrollView:
                        MDGridLayout:
                            cols: 3                                 
                            adaptive_height: True               
                            adaptive_width: True        
                            spacing: '10dp'
                            padding: ['10dp', '10dp']
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'Hello dear'                        
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'Lovely'
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'See you'
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'Later'                        
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'Forever'
                            MyImageCard:
                                source: root.image
                                caption: 'Good Bye'

"""


class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Also you were missing an indentation level after the second Scrollview, but that was not the source of the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through my code... I changed the size of the boxlayout with content from .55 to 1, because I don't want them to overlap at all. but in doing so, it made the contents of second boxlayout to be hidden. I cant scroll through vertically to see the contents not showing, I can only scroll the cards horizontally, please how do I fix this..

Comment: @Edwin You have to change the number of columns of the second layout so they span down. Also add `adaptive_height: True` to enable vertical scrolling. I have updated the answer with revised code so it works as you need (If it works you can accept it).

Comment: I haven't been able to reply due to the windows 10 wifi connectivity issue, it's killing me.
I really appreciate all your help, its scrolling quite all right now, the issue is that I don't want the second boxlayout to overlay anything, I don't want it to even show, until all the contents of the first boxlayout have been scrolled to the end then you get to the content of the second boxlayout (well in this case the content of the first boxlayout, are not much, but I hope you understand).

Comment: Ohhh, well, then probably you need the second BoxLayout to be the last child of the first one(not the main one, the one with the scroll view). Move it inside of the first scrollview in the kv string. I hope that's what you need.

Comment: I don't quite get you, do you mean I should indent the second boxlayout into the first or the contents of the second into the first?? and I have tried to indent the second boxlayout into the first it doesn't solve this..

Comment: Yes, increasing the indentation should work. I think the second layout should actually be a child of the first GridLayout. I'll modify the code to reflect that. However I don't know what will be the effect of the changes on the scrolling.

Comment: It took some more than just an indentation, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pos_hint` and `size_hint` to get what I think you want. Start your `kv` with:

```
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.5  # use half the available height of the MDScreen
        pos_hint: {'top':1}  # position at the top of the MDSCreen
```

and for the second `MDBoxLayout` add similar code:

```
    MDBoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.5  # use half the available height of the MDScreen
        pos_hint: {'y':0}  # position at the bottom of the MDSCreen
```